# Vagrant user doesn't seem to natively have sudo/root permissions

Tags: nginx, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, user-permissions

I'm trying to determine if there's a bug in Vagrant or in nginx.

I have the following `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.1.7"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 9005
end
```

So I run `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` and the server provisions and spins up. I want to *manually* install nginx on my new VM, so (per [the instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) for installing nginx on Ubuntu 14.04) I then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

nginx installs. I run `mkdir ~/mysite` and then I change its `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file to:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /home/vagrant/mysite;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

And then I run `nginx -s reload`. The error I receive is:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ nginx -s reload
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2016/12/22 00:36:48 [notice] 1442#0: signal process started
2016/12/22 00:36:48 [alert] 1442#0: kill(890, 1) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
```

My understanding is that `vagrant` should be a user on the VM with sudo access and root permissions. No? Can anyone reproduce this and figure out why I'm unable to reload nginx with my custom `nginx.conf` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vagrant user has indeed `sudo` privilegies but its not because it has this right that he can run command as root. As you did run `sudo apt-get update` with sudo, you need to run nginx with sudo :

```
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Thanks @Frederic Henri (+1) - however when I run your command I now get the following error: `nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`...any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: check if nginx is running `ps -edf | grep nginx` and kill all processes then start again

Comment: Thanks again, but no process is running. The output of running that grep just produces the results for the actual grep (`vagrant   1728  1102  0 15:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx`). Re-running `sudo nginx -s reload` produces the same error as before.

Comment: Interesting...I ran `perl -e '$0="sadhadxk"; sleep infinity' &` to create a dummy perl pid, and Ubuntu created a pid of 1782 for it. So I wrote 1782 into the file at `/var/run/nginx.pid` (which I had to create) and then I reloaded nginx (with sudo). When I did that I got the following output: `[1]+  Hangup                  perl -e '$0="sadhadxk"; sleep infinity'`. So clearly nginx found the file, read the pid out of the file, and killed the pid. I then ran `ps -aef | grep nginx` but nginx was still not running.

Comment: So its almost like nginx is failing to create the pid file the first time it runs, and then fails to write a new pid and/or start up each time I reload. Definitely smells like a linux permission issue.

Comment: just remove the nginx.pid file, nginx will need to own the file, if you create yourself there will be conflict

Comment: Right, but I think you're forgetting that there was never a pid file there in the first place, because (for some reason) nginx can't create it. I had to create it manually and then write a pid inside of it. When I remove the file and re-run `sudo nginx -s reload`, I get the original error message: `nginx: [error] open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.

Comment: ok but can you just remove the pid file, restart the VM and then do `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start` you'll see if there's an error, you can also check to /var/logs/nginx for error details

Comment: Hey! That did it! **Thank you!** So, as a post-mortem, for some reason nginx wasn't able to create the pid file (and/or wasn't able to eve start) when I installed it via `sudo apt-get install nginx`. To fix it I had to: (1) run a dummy process to give me a pid that I felt comfortable killing, (2) wrote that process' pid to `/var/run/nginx.pid`, (3) reloaded nginx via `sudo nginx -s reload`, (4) deleted the pid file, (5) restarted my VM and (6) ran `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start`. If you have any clue as to the cause of the problem, please, create an answer, and I'll give you the green check!

Comment: I am not sure about your previous steps - If you want to test, just destroy your VM and create a new one, install (`sudo apt-get install nginx`) and skip to step 5